# How can I run a .py file with its options in Python console?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run [this GitHub project](https://github.com/microsoft/tf-gnn-samples) in python, but I could only run it using the Terminal of Pycharm IDE.

According to the guide from the GitHub repository, I removed the `$` sign from the beginning of `$ python train.py RGCN PPI` and could run it there. What does `$` mean here and how can I run a file like this in Python Console (for example after `>>>` sign)?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: The dollar sign is simply to represent a terminal command line. You correctly surmised you want to run what is to right of it.

Comment: @Todd I am using Python 3

Comment: Give the 2nd example I have below a try and see if that works for you. @Ali

Comment: @Ali I've updated this answer after some experimenting with PyCharm. Forget the PyDev debugger - all you need is PyCharm and to do a few configuration steps. See answer for details.

Comment: @Ali sorry for leading you astray on PyDev remote debugging. I had a project that embedded Python and couldn't start it directly from the Eclipse debugger, so remote debugging was my only option. So I was thinking with that when I was trying to figure out how you could run these scripts. But that was a different beast.

Comment: @Todd I put the options in parameters in Debug configuration and I could run it line by line. Thank you very much. Love you :)

Comment: You're very welcome @Ali =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '$' isn't part of Python's syntax, it's a visual cue in the documentation representing the command prompt.

> To answer the question from the title of this post, I'll provide some
>   instructions first on how to load scripts into the Python console.
>   However, for your specific case, you don't need this. Scroll down to
>   the part about debugging in PyCharm.

There's two ways you can get your script into the console. One is to simply load it using the right version of the two lines I give right below, or you can load it as a module - even if it wasn't intended to be one.

In general, to execute a script in the Python shell on Python 2 you can do

```
>>> execfile(r"<path to script here>")
```

On Python 3 it's more verbose:

```
>>> exec(open(r"<path to script here>").read())
```

The effect this has is as if you cut-n-pasted the script into the console. The console's global scope will get all the functions, classes, and variables that are leftmost indented in the file. Also it might not run your `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. But you could hack that.

If you want the vars/classes/etc to be put in another scope than your console's global scope, then there are two additional parameters to the above commands. The first one is a dictionary for the `globals` , and one for the `locals`. You can get away with only supplying the `globals` parameter - it's just an ordinary dictionary object you need.

If the file you want to load is a module, you could import it as you would any other module by appending its home folder to the Python module search path, and using the `import` directive. You can load your script this way even if it wasn't intended to be module.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r'/Users/todd/projects/mymodule_folder')
>>> import mymodule
```

If you make modifications to it and want to reload it:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload(mymodule)
```

Loading your script as a module avoids polluting your console's global scope. After it loads, just prefix the names of your script's functions and variables with the module name. The module name will be the name of the file without the `.py` extension.

If the script requires command line options, you could just hard code values for those into the script and disable lines of code that try and get values from the CLI. If it gets complicated, consider running it in an IDE as described in the next section.

So the above is how you can run your python scripts in whatever Python REPL console you want.

> **BUT loading your scripts into the Python console may not be at all 
>   required for your purposes. You wanted to debug some scripts (train.py, 
>   test.py) from this project: 
>   https://github.com/microsoft/tf-gnn-samples).**

### Debugging Command Line Script With PyCharm

In many cases, a Python script is written to run from the OS shell and take command line options from the user. These kinds of script could be loaded into the Python console, but most require some minor hacks to run. However, if all you want to do is debug such a script, you don't need to muck with the console.

PyCharm supports running these as is (as does Eclipse and other IDEs) like any other script. It's just a matter of creating a run/debug configuration for the project. I just installed PyCharm and gave it a try in order to record the details. Easy task.

Just open the project in PyCharm, and above the editor pane, on the toolbar, there's a menu option for *Edit Configurations*. Click that to open the *Run/Debug Configurations* dialog and click the `+` to add a configuration. A small dialog will appear with predefined templates - select `Python` as your template and accept.

Then in the main dialog, fill in *Script path:* with the path to *train.py* (or another script), then click the checkbox, *[x] Emulate terminal in output console*. **Also, you can add command line options in the *Parameters:* text box** (I put in the text: `mymodel mytask` just to satisfy the script's need for two parameters). Click *OK* at the bottom to accept the configuration and shut the dialog.

Now you should see a green bug icon on the toolbar.Set a breakpoint in the `__main__` block of the script and click the debug icon to start debugging the script. That should do it!

### Debugging Python Command Line Script with PDB

PDB - the Python Debugger can be run without an IDE. This is another way to debug a script of any sort. If it requires command line parameters, provide them from the OS shell when you start the debugger:

```
$ pdb myscript.py mymodel mytask
```

That's really all there is to starting a debug session. PDB requires some knowledge of its text based commands. After starting a session, you can get a listing of code near the current line of execution by entering `l`. Enter `help` to see a listing of the commands.

To step one line of execution, enter 's' for step, or enter 'step'. To set a breakpoint, enter `break <line-number>`, or set a breakpoint on an expression. A reference on the commands available can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html . There are also plenty of versions of pdb cheatsheets available online - just google "pdb cheatsheet" and select one.

Comment: @Todd Thanks for your time but I could not run it using this way. Notice that in 'python train.py RGCN PPI' there are MODEL_NAME (here RGCN) and TASK_NAME (here PPI) after train.py and they are required to run this code!

Comment: @Ali well, your question in the title asks how to run a python file in the console.

Comment: @Ali okay. I updated this answer with some instructions to get you started if you really do need to run this from the Python console.

Comment: @Todd Sorry for the confusion. In that case, execfile ('.../file.py') would do the job. I edited the title and added the options.

Comment: @Ali no worries. Hopefully the additional info I gave might give you an idea of what's involved to get this to run. If you want more info on any of it, just @ me in comment.

Comment: @Todd Yes, I understand what you're saying. The reason that I want to run this code in the console is that I just want to debug the code line by line and understand what's going on inside other .py functions. Do you know how to debug such a file in python Terminal in Pycharm IDE?